# Criar um array em PHP a partir de uma variavél e organizar de forma decrescente

Tags: php, array, array-associativo

Boa Tarde, estou realizando um trabalho de escola, e preciso exibir as máquinas e o número de problemas que elas deram, gostaria de exibir de forma decrescente.

Porém após dar uma olhada, eu achei melhor criar um array mais organizado com essas informações, de modo que ele ficasse assim:

```
array(
'Retro Escavadeira' => 5,
'Cavadeira' => 2,
'Pa' => 3
);
```

E após isso, tentar organizar o array de forma decrescente e exibir em forma de tabela html.

No momento já estou exibindo em forma de tabela, mas os itens não estão em forma decrescente, vou postar meu código como está:

```
<?php
$arquivo = file("arquivos/etiqueta.txt");

foreach ($arquivo as $imprime) {
    print_r($imprime);
}

$arquivo = 'arquivos/etiqueta.txt';

$nomedasmaquinas = 'arquivos/nomedasmaquinas.txt';

$handle = fopen( $arquivo, 'r' );

$handle2 = fopen( $nomedasmaquinas, 'r' );

$ler = fread( $handle, filesize($arquivo) );
$ler2 = fread( $handle2, filesize($nomedasmaquinas) );

$procurar = $ler; //Esta vindo de um arquivo que contem as informacoes das maquinas, como um texto longo (EX: Nome da maquina: Cavadeira Linha: 1 Gravidade: Media etc...)
$nome_das_maquinas_str = $ler2; //Esta vindo de um arquivo, e as palavras estão separadas por . Ex(Cavadeira, Cavadeira, RetroEscavadeira)

$array = explode('.', "$nome_das_maquinas_str"); //Separo as palavras por . e gravo no array
$array_nomes = array_values(array_unique($array));
$array_count = array_count_values($array);
?>

<table>
<?php
echo "<table>";
//Bloco Das maquinas com problemas
$i = 0;
for($i = 0; $i <= count($array_count) - 2; $i++){ //Ao invés de exibir, eu queria criar um array como exibido acima e depois printar de forma organizada.
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $array_nomes[$i] . "</td>". 
    "<td>". $array_count[$array_nomes[$i]] . "</td>";
}

echo "</table>"
?>
</table>

<?php
// Fecha o arquivo
fclose($handle);
fclose($handle2);
?>
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Caso queira exibir em ordem alfabética, para esse caso, recomendo ksort https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 0):

No PHP temos as seguintes funções:

- `sort` => ordena o array pelo seu valor
- `rsort` => ordena o array, em ordem reversa pelo seu valor e não mantém a associação dos índice
- `asort` => ordena o array pelo valor mantendo a associação dos índice, para ordem reversa use arsort

Então você quer ordenar pelo valor use a função `arsort`.
Modo de uso:

```
$a = array( 'a' => 1, 'c' => 4, 'b' => 3);
arsort($a);
```

Resultado:

```
'c' => 4,
'b' => 3,
'a' => 1
```

Depois só apresentar os dados.